# Set border image over previous div to make peek kind of effect for image

Tags: html, css

Sorry guys I made new one for this because it couldn't be done like I previously explained.

I want image to go over previous div and so it stays always at the same exact spot.

It's an border image for portfolio div what I'm trying to align here correctly, so that it makes peek kind of effect over previous div.

```
<div id="previous">some content</div>
<div id="portfolio">
    <div class="some-other-content">Whole lot of html</div>
</div>
```

[Link to my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Konzaales/cNT24/5/)

Comment: What do you mean, that makes little to no sense.

Comment: also, your fiddle has an error in the html, fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/cNT24/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use in your CSS

"position:absolut" to set a fix position in your Window.

see more options here:

http://www.css4you.de/position.html